# Game mysql table: How to count only first attempt per user and provide total SUM of correct/incorrect?

Tags: mysql

I have created a game where users can answer quiz questions - as many times as they want. See [example question here](http://www.fragesport.de/31/welches-grundrechten-deutschen-verfassung-garantiert-werden) (stats are in the sidebar top right).

Currently I am only counting the total statistics, i. e. all attempts of all users. This, of course, is falsifying the per question statistics.

```
SELECT SUM(correct=1) AS correct, SUM(correct=0) AS incorrect, timestamp 
    FROM `gametable` 
    WHERE questionid = #
```

Example date for the gametable:

```
+---------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| timestamp           | userid | questionid | correct |
+---------------------+--------+------------+---------+
| 2014-12-07 15:38:35 |      1 |         33 |       0 |
| 2014-12-07 15:39:40 |      1 |         33 |       1 |
| 2014-12-07 15:41:40 |      1 |         33 |       1 |
| 2014-12-07 16:00:17 |      2 |         33 |       1 |
| 2014-12-07 16:08:00 |      2 |         33 |       0 |
| 2014-12-07 16:09:00 |      2 |         33 |       0 |
| 2014-12-07 16:10:25 |      2 |         33 |       1 |
+---------------------+--------+------------+---------+
```

The result for the above table with the mysql query given would be: 4 correct and 3 incorrect.

However, the **"first attempt" result** should be: **1 correct and 1 incorrect**.

Is there a way to write a mysql query to do this?

Comment: Use a sub query to find the first attempt for each user id, and then join the results of that back against the table to get the details for the first attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a sub query to get the first attempt for each user:-

```
SELECT SUM(correct=1) AS correct, SUM(correct=0) AS incorrect
FROM `gametable` 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, MIN(timestamp) AS mintimestamp
    FROM `gametable` 
    GROUP BY userid
) sub0
ON gametable.userid = sub0.userid
WHERE questionid = #
AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp
```

Note I have removed the timestamp column from your outer select as it didn't appear to be required, nor would it bring back a meaningful value.

Note that your sample data doesn't include a question field, but your example SQL does. Assuming you do have a question field you would need to select the first attempt for the particular question as well:-

```
SELECT SUM(correct=1) AS correct, SUM(correct=0) AS incorrect
FROM `gametable` 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, questionid, MIN(timestamp) AS mintimestamp
    FROM `gametable` 
    GROUP BY userid, questionid
) sub0
ON gametable.userid = sub0.userid
AND gametable.questionid = sub0.questionid
AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp
WHERE gametable.questionid = #
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(correct=1) AS correct, SUM(correct=0) AS incorrect
FROM `gametable` 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, MIN(timestamp) AS mintimestamp
    FROM `gametable` 
    WHERE gametable.questionid = #
    GROUP BY userid
) sub0
ON gametable.userid = sub0.userid
AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp
```

EDIT - Suggestion to cope with anonymous users based on a cookie id. This is returning the cookie id if the user id is null, otherwise it is returning null for the cookie id. Done like this so that the cookie id is ignored for records with a user id.

```
SELECT SUM(correct=1) AS correct, SUM(correct=0) AS incorrect
FROM `gametable` 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid, if(userid IS NULL, cookie_id, NULL) AS cookie_id, questionid, MIN(timestamp) AS mintimestamp
    FROM `gametable` 
    GROUP BY userid, cookie_id, questionid
) sub0
ON ((gametable.userid IS NULL
AND gametable.cookie_id = sub0.cookie_id)
OR (gametable.userid IS NOT NULL
AND gametable.userid = sub0.userid))
AND gametable.questionid = sub0.questionid
AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp
WHERE gametable.questionid = #
```

Comment: Thx for your answer! `postid` from the example table is supposed to be `questionid`. I have made an edit.

Comment: Regarding query II: Adding `AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp` works now :) thx mate. I also added `WHERE questionid = #` to the INNER JOIN right before `GROUP BY userid, questionid`

Comment: This is not the end of the story. I have started to allow anonymous users to play the quiz, they get identified by `cookieid` and the `userid` is NULL. Would this be a simple addition to the query (I am using query II now) or should I open a new question here on stackoverflow?

Comment: I have added a suggestion but not tested it.

Comment: The inner join query `SELECT userid, IF(userid IS NULL, cookie_id, NULL) AS cookie_id, questionid, MIN(timestamp) AS mintimestamp FROM gametable WHERE questionid = # GROUP BY userid, cookie_id, questionid` gives me all users and anonymous, first time active on this question, great! 1. Using the entire query, I think it must be `AND (gametable.userid IS NOT NULL 
OR (gametable.userid IS NULL` (the NOT seems to be on the wrong position). 2. It only works when I remove `AND gametable.timestamp =  sub0.mintimestamp` otherwise NULL | NULL?

Comment: I guess the part `ON qa_quizx_gameplay.userid = sub0.userid` could be a problem if both fields are NULL. I am note sure if mysql evaluates NULL = NULL here.

Comment: Yes, well spotted. Amended it.

Comment: Fantastic help. I just added `WHERE questionid = #` into the inner join to narrow down the results from the beginning. You are really professional, thank you :)